# Notepad++: Delete everything after a number of characters in string

Tags: regex, notepad++, limit

The following is an example of 24 characters per line in Notepadd ++. I need to limit the characters per line to 14 characters.

> Hell, how is she today ?

I need it to look like the following:

> Hell, how is

I used this code

```
Find what: ^(.{1,14}).*
Replace with: $1
```

However, it show "Hell, how is s", it is misspelled.

How can I can limit the number of characters to 14 characters per line in Notepad++ and delete last word ?

Comment: `Hell, how is s` has 14 characters.

Comment: try `^(.{14}).*` and replace the match with `$1`

Comment: I think OP means that the line should be *at most* 14 characters, but should be truncated further if it would cut a word in half. So instead of keeping the 's' of 'she', the whole word should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Find what:    `^(.{1,14}(?<=\S)\b).*$`

Replace with:     `$1`

so for `Hell, how is she today ?` the output is: `Hell, how is`

<kbd>[`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/wX9jU3/1)</kbd>

```
^                # The beginning of the string
(                # Group and capture to \1:
  .{1,14}        # Any character except \n (between 1 and 14 times (matching the most amount possible))
  (?<=\S)        # This lookbehind makes sure the last char is not a space
  \b             # The boundary between a word char (\w). It matches the end of a word in this case
)                # End of \1
.*$              # Match any char till the end of the line
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want:

Find what: `^(.{1,14}) .*$`
Replace with: `$1`

This will truncate at 14 characters or less if there is a space.

Comment: Consider the case with multiple spaces

Answer (score 1):

Also could use [\K](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) as a variable length lookbehind and replace with nothing:

```
^.{0,13}\w\b\K.*
```

`\w` matches a [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), `\b` a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

[Test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cK4dY5/2)