# How do I remove everything after the first 4 or 5 letters of a string notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text document on notepad++ filled with things

```
V307G5C
V307G57
V307G5X
V307G54
V307G57
V307G5Y
V307G58
V307G5L
V307G56
V307G5M
```

And I want them to be like this

```
V307
V307
V307
V307
V307
V307
V307
V307
V307
V307
```

How do I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++: Delete everything after a number of characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124538/notepad-delete-everything-after-a-number-of-characters-in-string)  (since you love regex.... )

Comment: For your sample I would use `G.*` and `Replace` leave it empty .....

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use [`\K` which resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match:

```
^.{4}\K.+
```

And replace with empty string. See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RuBjnN/2).

NP++ replace options: [•] regular expressions, [ ] . matches newline

Comment: Hello!

I was trying to read and understand this. How does it know to not keep deleting everything in the next line?

Comment: @Iloveregex The dot does not match newlines, if it does: Uncheck [ ] `. matches newline` in np++.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in find/replace dialog:

Find what: `(^....).*`
Replace with: `\1`
⦿ Regular expression

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>